# ASP.NET MVC model binding precedence vs. RESTful resources

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, model-binding, restful-url, restful-architecture

The order of precedence that ASP.NET MVC uses when it binds models for incoming requests is bothering me in the context of REST.  Essentially, MVC binds models using values in the following order of precedence:

- POST body
- Route (URL)
- Query string values

What bothers me is how that trumps a resource's Uri with values from the body of the message.

For example, I could have a RESTful resource exposed as follows:

```
/dogs/
```

... returning:

```
[{
    'name': 'Fido',
    'color': 'brown',
    '_links': {
        'self': { 'href': '/dogs/7' }
    }
},
{
    'name': 'Spot',
    'color': 'spotted',
    '_links': {
        'self': { 'href': '/dogs/5' }
    }
}]
```

Note that with the "self" link ([HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) style), I have everything I need to modify the dogs by PUTting those resources back to the server without needing their "id" values.

```
PUT /dogs/7
{
    'name': 'Super Fido',
    'color': 'rainbow'
}
```

The server has everything needed to update the dog, with no confusion.  MVC will model-bind everything nicely into my model, including the id (sourced from the route).

However, some API styles I have seen include the 'id' in the message body, so that it looks like this:

```
GET /dogs/7
{
    'id': 7,
    'name': 'Super Fido',
    'color': 'rainbow'
}
```

But fundamentally what bothers me the most is that if I have a route defined like "{controller}/{id}", and the client does the following:

```
PUT /dogs/7
{
    'id': 5,
    'name': 'Snowy',
    'color': 'white'
}
```

... then MVC will model bind the 'id' to 5 (from the message body), and not 7 (from the route), yet based on the resource URI that my client provided, they should have been updating Fido's information.  This would be akin to trying to save a document to your hard drive in a certain location, and because of something in the document, having it be automatically saved somewhere else.

How would one go about changing the out-of-the-box model binding precedence in ASP.NET MVC to prioritize the route values over the message body (when conflicts exist), and would this be a good thing to do in this context?

Comment: Have you ever found an answer? I'm dealing with a similar issue now between values from HTTP body and GET.